# EditText value to countdowntimer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to assign a value which the user input into the edit text as the start value of the countdown timer converting it to milliseconds

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    minutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    seconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counting);

    final String sec = String.valueOf(seconds.getText());
    int sec1 = Integer.valueOf(sec);
    long sec2 = sec1;
    //String minu = minutes.getText().toString();

     final CountDownTimer counting = new 
       CountDownTimer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec2), 1000) {
           @Override
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               Log.i("alarm rings in",                      
                   String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
           }

           @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                Log.i("done", "alarm is ringing");
            }
        };

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counting.start();
        }

    });
}
```

}

I'm Expecting the count down to start upon clicking of the button but instead it displays the Onfinish() method output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and it looks good, see:

```
    val sec2 = 10L
    val counting: CountDownTimer =
        object : CountDownTimer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec2), 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.i("alarm rings in", (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString())
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                Log.i("alarm done", "alarm is ringing")
            }
        }

    counting.start()
```

```
2019-09-09 00:06:57.791 1258-1654/? I/HwAlarmManagerService: hwSetAlarm listenerTag: *job.delay*
2019-09-09 00:06:59.740 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 9
2019-09-09 00:07:00.004 1258-1258/? I/HwAlarmManagerService: hwSetAlarm listenerTag: time_tick
2019-09-09 00:07:00.741 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 8
2019-09-09 00:07:01.742 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 7
2019-09-09 00:07:02.742 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 6
2019-09-09 00:07:03.743 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 5
2019-09-09 00:07:04.744 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 4
2019-09-09 00:07:05.745 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 3
2019-09-09 00:07:06.746 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 2
2019-09-09 00:07:07.748 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 1
2019-09-09 00:07:08.749 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm rings in: 0
2019-09-09 00:07:09.232 26157-26157/com.unest.android.dev I/alarm done: alarm is ringing
2019-09-09 00:07:12.378 1258-1379/? W/AlarmManager: mIsScreenOn is: true, WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD package name is: com.google.android.gms
2019-09-09 00:07:12.378 1258-1379/? W/AlarmManager: mIsScreenOn is: true, WAKEUP alarm talarm.operation == null,package name is: android listenerTag is: *job.delay* creator uid is: 1000
2019-09-09 00:07:12.411 1258-1258/? I/HwAlarmManagerService: hwSetAlarm listenerTag: *job.delay*
```

Probably you set 1 second and finish was fired. Try to increase the number of seconds in edittext or set different interval from 1000 ms

Comment: Thanks...I changed the default seconds value to 30sec and the countdown worked....but if it is edited through the app the countdown still starts from 30seconds instead of the updated number

Comment: @Wisdom, you are welcome. Try do debug starting from this line: `final String sec = String.valueOf(seconds.getText());`.

Comment: See my answer. I initially stated the problem you have.

Comment: Thanks ...fixed the problem....just had to put the countdown and gettext in the button onclicklistener ....thank you and everyone in the comment

Answer (score 0):

According to [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long,%20long)) for CountDownTimer class (see its constructor), the value of millisInFuture parameter is less than the value of countDownInterval parameter. So onFinish is executed before onTick.